# In a solar farm why isn't there a single gigantic solar panel across all the farm surface, rather than small individual separate panels?

Tags: energy, solar-cells

Why don't we just cover all the farm surface with one solar panel? Why is there a necessity for making separate but multiple panels rather than one large panel that covers the whole necessary space?

Comment: A panel that's inclineded towards the south will be more efficient per dollar of solar panel than one lying flat - if we're in the Northern hemisphere. And it's hard to incline a gigantic panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what it would take to build something like that.  Where would you do it? How would you transport it?  How would you maneuver it to follow the sun?  What happens if it breaks?  How could you repair such a thing, or perform maintenance on it from above?

Now think about the benefits.  Based on this image, it looks like making all of those solar panels contiguous would roughly double the density of solar cells.

[image]

But who cares about that?  If you want more solar cells, just double the size of your farm. You don't need them to be packed close together - lack of space is not the limiting factor here.

So **tl;dr**: (1) It would be physically impossible and (2) in every way that it differs from a normal solar array, it would be actively harmful - except for the fact that it would increase the spatial density of solar cells, which is by and large irrelevant anyway.

Comment: You've made your point: this is engineering not physics. This question should be closed.

Comment: @my2cts You've made your point as well...?

Comment: I would add to the list of disadvantages, that the output voltage of one big cell would only be a single cell voltage of 0.6 Volts, which either severely limits the applications for storage and consumption, or requires step-up conversion, which results in additional losses. Contrary to that, having multiple cells in series boosts voltage at no cost.

Comment: @my2cts I am an engineering physics student and this is what we see in the solid state physics. We do not have a separate stack website.

Comment: @CemTuğanlı Engineering is very interesting and important, there should be no mistake about it!

Comment: Actually there is an engineering site: https://engineering.stackexchange.com.